# jQuery: On document load check if checkbox is selected and do function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few `<li>`'s with a checkbox on each `<li>` which the value of it is saved into a database. On document load, the `<li>`'s that have the checkbox selected, I want to add a class **'.done'**.

I tried this:

```
if (currentTODO.find('.status').is(":checked")) {
            currentTODO.find('.text').addClass("done");
            alert('Test.');
    }
```

but it works only if it used under click function, mousemove etc but not on document load. Also, If I have that piece of code under on Document load, nothing else works.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][checked="checked"]').parent().addClass('done');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBMEm/

**Edit**:  This might be closer to what you were trying to do:

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('input').is(':checked');
}).addClass('done');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBMEm/7/

I have no problem with any of these working on document load.

**Edit**:  Incidentally, as is often the case with a jQuery-based solution, you can just do this in CSS:

```
input:checked:after {
    margin-left: 20px;
    content: "Done";
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3SRQd/

Unless you're interested in doing something else with it programmatically or need it to actually have the class for some other reason.

**Extra edit**:  How about this?  http://jsfiddle.net/EDs3N/12/  (Incidentally, I'm headed home.)

Comment: can you set a class for the input?

Comment: Yes.  I was assuming you wanted it on the parent ``li``, but you could set it on the child instead.  Then you just need to go with the first approach: ``$('input[type="checkbox"][checked="checked"]').addClass('done');``

Comment: Can you please read what I said to austibv? I think your answer is really close to my question

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EDs3N/ Note that it won't work because there is no database connection etc. On the current fiddle, when I mouseover each selected <li> it add's the class.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce the issues with this not working on documentload, unless I do it using jQuery's special selectors like: ``$('input:checkbox:checked').addClass('done');``  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SBMEm/24/  Note that you're limited in what styling you can do on a checkbox.

Comment: I want to class to be added on another div inside the <li>. Check my fiddle. It's a <li> with 4 different things. If the checkbox is selected, I want to add class another div inside the li.

Comment: Your last edit looks awesome. Can I do that though, if checked change the content of other div? Please check my fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/EDs3N and maybe http://www.screenr.com/IMgs

Comment: This works: $('input:checkbox:checked.status').addClass('done');. But I want to add the class to a different div. Is that possible?

Comment: Your fiddle would never actually work because you need to specify using jQuery instead of MooTools, and everything in the JS window automatically runs on document load. :P  I've had some luck with:  http://jsfiddle.net/EDs3N/12/

Comment: I don't know how can I thank you. I've been banging my head for 3 days!

Answer (score 0):

yo need to call your function in here

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   currentTODO.find('.status').is(":checked")) {   //or whatever code yo are using
            currentTODO.find('.text').addClass("done");
            alert('Test.');
};
```

Comment: Please read my question. " but it works only if it used under click function, mousemove etc but not on document load. "

Comment: that means the markup does not exist on the page when the doc is loaded which means it doesnt make sense for you to do it then

Comment: I didn't set a downvote. Sir I can't do a jsFiddle because there's alot of PHP. What I said to austinbv is this: On mouse over each <li>, it adds the class. On document load it doesn't because currentTODO is each <li> you're working on. So on document load, I'm trying to add a Class on the currentTodo status, which there is no currentTodo at the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Why not runt he check when the document loads

```
function check_checkbox () {
  if (currentTODO.find('.status').is(":checked")) {
            currentTODO.find('.text').addClass("done");
            alert('Test.');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   check_checkbox()
}
```

or if you define it inside the doc ready which you shouldn't do but if you did

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function check_checkbox () {
    if (currentTODO.find('.status').is(":checked")) {
      currentTODO.find('.text').addClass("done");
      alert('Test.');
    }
  }()
}
```

Comment: You could also simplify that to `$(document).ready(check_checkbox)` since it's a function itself.

Comment: I was just going to ask where the `currentTODO` is coming from

Comment: whats with the -1? and yes pimvdb you could do that but I assume people put more crap in the doc ready.  And @mazzzzz its from the asker, I am assuming its a JQ object that s/he saved to a variable to use later

Comment: It is the variable for each <li>.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working. I tried it before. What seems to be the problem is that: On mouse over each <li>, it adds the class. On document load it doesn't because currentTODO is each <li> you're working on. So on document load, I'm trying to add a Class on the currentTodo status, which there is no currentTodo at the time being.